# Selenium does not get elements loaded later

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to make a python script that will log into my router's page, log all the connected devices, and then display them by their connected names.
I have made a script that looks like this:

```
from requests import session
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep


url = "http://192.168.1.1/login/login.html"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 100)
browser.get(url)
kad = browser.find_element_by_id("AuthName")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("AuthPassword")
kad.send_keys("MyRouterLoginName")
password.send_keys("MyRouterLoginPassword")
buton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li/div[3]/form/fieldset/ul/li[6]/input") #this is my login button
buton.click()
homepage = "http://192.168.1.1/index.html"
browser.get(homepage) #Router asks for changing default password, i skip it like that
sleep(5)
verify = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('body')
print(verify.text) #see my later explanation
xpathmethod = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/ul[1]/li[1]/div[2]/a")
print(xpathmethod.text)
print("Finding by css")
content = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.addmenu')
print(content.text)
```

The verify line was to make sure the webpage was fully loaded but here is the problem, while webpage loads, it first loads a default menu items (Such as connection status, Networking settings, troubleshooting etc) then loads the devices that are currently connected. Webdriver somehow does not recognize the connected devices section and gives an "unable to locate element" error.
I have tried xpath and css selector methods but both gives me the same result.
Sorry, I can't paste the html fully but here is the path that chrome gives me when I inspect the element

```
html body div.index div div #mainframe html body div div #contentPanel #mapView div div table tbody tr td div #wlInfo li div a
```

Comment: If your element inside iframe you have to switch to it first. Add html as text.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
try:
    # Load page
    browser.get("http://192.168.1.1/index.html")
    # Wait 10 seconds before element can be located on the page
    # For example, <div class="example"> -- first div with class "example"
    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='example'][1]")))
except Exception as e:
    # Catch an exception in case of element unavailability
    print ("Page load error: {}".format(e.message))
```

Answer (score 0):

Found another way to get connected devices list.
Modem has a ConnectionStatus page where it gives me a full list including mac addresses and other details in a single string.
Now I need to parse them. Will create another question about that.