# Parse a string between special characters and build a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I was trying to make a script that will give the devices that are connected to my network. [My last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52230128/selenium-does-not-get-elements-loaded-later/) was the issue with finding elements with selenium, but i found another way to get them.
Now i get a full string of the details of all devices that are connected to my wifi network. It looks like this:

```
@ @ pc/devicename1/ConnectedProtocol (usually 802.11)/Device mac address/DHCP/local ip adress/a random number that i don't want to use /another number that i don't want to use/ipv6 address/:ipv6::|pc/devicename1/ConnectedProtocol (usually 802.11)/Device mac address/DHCP/local ip adress/a random number that i don't want to use/another number that i don't want to use/ipv6 address/:ipv6 address::|@ 0@ 0|0|0|0@ 1@
```

So a normal device list looks like this:

```
@ @pc/android-d45cb2db4c2da/802.11/12:34:56:78:90:ab/DHCP/192.168.1.2/2/1/fe60::84c5:6de3:fe65:6bd8/:84c5:6de3:fe65:6bd8/::|pc/android-cd4b56add5/802.11/12:34:56:78:90:ab/DHCP/192.168.1.3/2/35/fe60::1547:bbb:fe69:8441/:2605:fff:fe97:9145/::@ 0@ 1|0|0|0@ 1@
```

Output should be like this:

- Device name: android-d45cb2db4c2da
- Mac address: 12:34:56:78:90:ab
- Local ip: 192.168.1.2
- Connection Protocol: Wlan

And then another device.
How do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the initial string into smaller substrings containing information of each device and then split again to get the desired information:

```
devices = "@ @pc/android-d45cb2db4c2da/802.11/12:34:56:78:90:ab/DHCP/192.168.1.2/2/1/fe60::84c5:6de3:fe65:6bd8/:84c5:6de3:fe65:6bd8/::|pc/android-cd4b56add5/802.11/12:34:56:78:90:ab/DHCP/192.168.1.3/2/35/fe60::1547:bbb:fe69:8441/:2605:fff:fe97:9145/::@ 0@ 1|0|0|0@ 1"
devices = devices.split("::|")
for device in devices:
    device = device.split("/")
    print("Device name: " + device[1])
    print("MAC address: " + device[3])
    print("Local IP: " + device[5])
    print("Connected protocol: " + device[2])
    print()
```

Output:

```
Device name: android-d45cb2db4c2da
MAC address: 12:34:56:78:90:ab
Local IP: 192.168.1.2
Connected protocol: 802.11

Device name: android-cd4b56add5
MAC address: 12:34:56:78:90:ab
Local IP: 192.168.1.3
Connected protocol: 802.11
```

Note: In order to determine whether you 're using a WLAN or Ethernet or any other protocol, it is best to create a dictionary with keys the IEEE naming standards e.g `802.11` and values the types of protocol e.g. `WLAN`.